# A single exception in Truffle test causes every other test cases to fail

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-test

I'm making test script for my contract and it looks likes

```
contract('...', async () => {
    let token = null;
    before('deploy', async () => {
        token = await MyContract.new(...);
    });

    it('should success', async() => { ... });
    it('should fail', async() => { ... });    // work as intended only until here
    it('should success', async() => { ... });
});
```

and executed with command `truffle test ./test/test.js`

Issue is that calls after second `it(...)`, which contract call fails and invoke `revert`, never succeed and raise errors similar to

```
AssertionError: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 37 tx has nonce of: 36
```

How do I make the test script work? looks like some kind of nonce increment gone wrong, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.
I'm using Ganache GUI 2.0.1 for test network and truffle v5.0.9.

-- Edit --

as comment suggested, I check if I missed any `await` keyword,

my code is all like this,

```
it('should deny transfer with insufficient (zero) balance', async () => {
    const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
    const promise = token.transfer.call(accounts[3], amount, { 'from': accounts[2] });
    await assert.isRejected(promise, 'revert', 'transfer transaction with insufficient (zero) balance must be denied');
});
```

I tried what Majd TL suggested also,

```
it('should deny transfer with insufficient (zero) balance', async () => {
    const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
    const promise = token.transfer(accounts[3], amount, { 'from': accounts[2] });
    await truffleAssert.reverts(promise, 'revert', 'transfer transaction with insufficient (zero) balance must be denied');
});
```

but it does not resolve the problem. The workaround now is to call contract call that expected to fail with `.call`, like

```
const promise = token.nope.call(1, 2, 3, { 'from': accounts[0] });
```

but in case of really unexpected error, it is inevitable and should be a thing. I Also see this error when using multiple `contract(...)`.

Comment: I bet you're missing an `await` somewhere...

Comment: what is amount and why it is too big?, also i'm saddly not javascript profi :) but maybe making the whole test in one line could change something, i mean -> await truffleAssert.reverts(token.transfer(accounts[3], 2, .......)

Comment: I think it's not caused by promise, because I managed to make it work by managing nonce per user by hand. So my guess is truffle does not handle nonce when there's errors and manual contract deployment has occurred. and, well I checked every promise I tossed : (

Comment: what does the amount value stand for?

Comment: `amount` value stands for 1 ether, (== 10**18). It seems to big but bignumber type can store and handle it. Also I thought it's not a uncommon to use this large value in token contract.

Answer (score 2):

```
token.transfer(accounts[3], amount, { 'from': accounts[2], nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accounts[2]) });
```

add the nonce parameter will fixed the problem, it work for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the truffle assertions library and as goodvibration said don't forget the **await**

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');    
...
it('should fail', async function () {
   await truffleAssert.fails(<your_contract>.<your_function>(..., { from: ... }));
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-assertions

Comment: thanks for reply, but it could not solve the problem. I replaced my code with your suggestion and check every line if I missed `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Friend actually truffle developer team has lost control over his project, patching one side creating problem on other side. ( even on their official forum 80% questions are not addressed and in most cases question is for X and reply is for Y ) Now I think they have only one way to start new project with similar goal with fresh and restructured foundation else day be day the project will move in to complexity and impossible to patch bug.